# Execute a query that joins tables from 2 or more db's with SQLConnector and SQLCommand

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

How do you execute a query like this;

```
    SELECT
    c.Name
    FROM db1..TableA a(nolock)
    join db2..TableA b(nolock) on a.id = b.id
    join db2..TableB c(nolock) on b.id = c.id
    join db2..TableC as d on c.id = d.id
    where c.id = '2314'
```

with `SQLConnector` and `SQLCommand` ? It seems like you're only able to connect to a single db at once.

I realize I could have two instances of `SQLConnector` and then join the results in my C# code but obviously that would be a terrible solution. Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: Are you running the query in `on the SQL Server`, or in your `C# Code`

Comment: @DJKRAZE In my C# code. Running it as a sproc would be a potential solution but not really what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Short of a database link in one of the instances your only choice is get both complete result sets and link within your c# code

Comment: I would suggest creating a `StoredProc` then on your `C#` side I will post a snippet of what you can use on your Client Side code and I would also lookup the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` Method..

Comment: Assuming `Events` and `Contacts` are different databases on the same SQL Server, (which the three part name implies), this code will run fine in SQL Server Management Studio and will not require a linked server. Why won't it run in C#?

Comment: @ElectricLlama I believe it's because the connection string requires a database to specified and thus only connects to single database instead of the db engine like in SSMS.

Comment: What kind of database / database driver is being used? If you use OLE DB or ADO or whatever to connect to a host/database then that should work, but yes, if you're using one of those MDF-type connections I guess it won't.

Comment: @ElectricLlama My answer has been up for two days on how to access multiple servers via a single connection and yet just 8 hours ago you state a connection is limited to a single database.

Comment: Your answer refers to 4 part names. OP refers to 3 part names? That SQL Syntax is only referring to one server. Perhaps your answer is alluding to something I'm missing.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I believe you're correct. I'm not linking servers. These db's are all on the same db engine. I'm just trying to find a reasonable way to do this other than using sprocs because I don't know that I have the access to do that.

Comment: Have you tried running that query through your `SQLCommand`? What error do you get? Have you tried running it through SQL Server Management Studio? What does your connection string look like? Does it mention and MDF file or a host (server) name?

Comment: In SSMS it works fine. Through the `SQLCommand` I believe I was getting an auth error. I gutted this today and replaced the data access layer with EF hoping that would work. I found that you can't use 2 contexts in a single query.

Comment: So did you get it working? Why do you need to use two different contexts? Are you submitting the SQL directly or using Linq. You probably can't do it through Linq. Is your problem solved now?

Comment: It's not solved. I was trying to use link. There's one context for each db, or I might be using the wrong term, either way different edmx files. I didn't spend much time trying to get working, had more important things to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you are referring to a single server then you can use three part name
But that name requires the owner which is usually dbo
Try

```
 SELECT
    c.Name
    FROM db1.dbo.TableA a(nolock)
    join db2.dbo.TableA b(nolock) on a.id = b.id
    join db2.dbo.TableB c(nolock) on b.id = c.id
    join db2.dbo.TableC as d on c.id = d.id
    where c.id = '2314'
```

If you right click the table in SSMS and click select top 1000 rows it will build the correct 3 part name.

If the databases are on separate servers.

Via linked servers you can access more than one server on a single connection.

[Linked Servers (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

[Create Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

Then you just refer to the 4 part name via a single connection
That 4 part name is not limited to SSMS
That 4 part name can be used by connection from .NET.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/) and SO [policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) link-only answers are discouraged. Not because of brevity, but because they do not answer the question directly and break easily. If you disagree with this, take it to meta instead of trying to argue for it in your answer. People can get links from, upvote, and reply to comments as well so there is no benefit in making links answers.

Comment: Further to this..... a link is not required as he is only using a three part name. If I understand the question, Linked servers are irrelevant here.

Comment: I'll give this a try though doubt it will work. In my example I'm just using `..` instead of `dbo`. I don't know the details about how that substitution works but it seems the `dbo` part is meaningless, it's there for every table so what can it really add? I still have the db and table in the name.

Comment: Alright that worked. Good to know I just need to add `dbo` and somehow it works... Although It could also be the fact that I added the edmx files for both db's (I think their lazily instantiated so it shouldn't impact it).

Comment: You might want to remove your reference to linked servers from your post as it is misleading.

Comment: @ElectricLlama What part of "If the databases are on separate servers" is misleading?  I think it add a lot to the answer in case you need to join across servers.

Comment: To the uninformed or inexperienced it is misleading as he is not joining across servers. . Anyway it's not important. Mainly I'm just trolling cause I was annoyed about your earlier comment "My answer has been up for two days ...". Your incorrect answer which you subsequently changed to align with my comments about not requiring a linked server! Doesn't matter not important, I can see we will not agree on this.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I meant to respond to OP not you.  Sorry.  You helped lead to a solution.  Again I opologize.

Comment: Oh sorry, my misunderstanding! No, I apologise! :)